# MySQL getting a table using sum

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a table out of three different tables. I managed to count the paid field but cant get the correct values for Fee.

```
The Customer Table
    ╔════╦═════════════╗
    ║ ID ║    NAME     ║
    ╠════╬═════════════╣
    ║  1 ║ John Smith  ║
    ║  2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║
    ╚════╩═════════════╝
    The Event table
    ╔════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
    ║ ID ║    Event    ║ Decription  ║    Fee      ║
    ╠════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
    ║  1 ║ Rock Music  ║ Interseting ║          80 ║
    ║  2 ║ Pop music   ║ Interseting ║          90 ║
    ╚════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝


    The Payment table
    ╔════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
    ║ ID ║already Paid ║ Customer_ID ║ Event_ID    ║
    ╠════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
    ║  1 ║  0          ║           1 ║          1  ║
    ║  2 ║ 90          ║           1 ║          2  ║
    ║    ║             ║             ║             ║
    ║  3 ║ 90          ║           2 ║          2  ║
    ║  4 ║ 80          ║           2 ║          1  ║
    ╚════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

i am trying to get this table paid refers to what he already paid and fee refers to the events´ that he has to pay

```
    ╔═══════╦══════════╦═══════╗
    ║Name   ║ paid     ║ Fee   ║
    ╠═══════╬══════════╬═══════╣
    ║John Sm║       90 ║  170  ║
    ║Jim Jim║      170 ║  170  ║
    ║       ║          ║       ║
    ║       ║          ║       ║
    ║       ║          ║       ║
    ║       ║          ║       ║
    ╚═══════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

untested:

```
select c.name, sum(p.paid), sum(e.fee)
  from customer c
  join payment  p on c.id       = p.customer_id
  join event    e on p.event_id = e.id
group by c.name;
```

Comment: I tried to get a list of each event at its participants using the same method but it shows only the first participant of the event not all of them. [My actual tables are more complicated than this table]

Comment: You have to `group by` every non-aggregate column, e.g. `select e.event, c.name, sum(p.paid), sum(e.fee) from ... group by e.event, c.name`.

Comment: I grouped by every non-aggregate column and now it works as it should.